# (Alembic, SQLAlchemy) Can I copy data from non partitioned key to a partitioned one in the migration script?

Tags: database, postgresql, sqlalchemy, partitioning, alembic

I have a table needs to be partitioned, but since the `postgresql_partition_by` wasn't added while the creation of the table so am trying to:

- create a new partitioned table that is similar the origin one.
- moving the data from the old one to the new one.
- drop the original one.
- rename the new one.
  so what is the best-practice to move the data from the old table to the new one ??

I tried this and it didn't work

```
COPY partitioned_table 
FROM original_table;
```

also tried

```
INSERT INTO partitioned_table (column1, column2, ...)
SELECT column1, column2, ...
FROM original_table;
```

but both didn't work :(
noting that I am using Alembic to generate the migration scripts also am using sqlalchemy from Python

Comment: `didn't work` is not an error message - pls specify the problem

Comment: It was raising syntax errors, but both were different ones.
@MarmiteBomber

Comment: Sorry, but no help available for either `didn't work` or `syntax errors` - you'll have to be more specific...

Comment: I have found the solution, ty!

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have two scenarios described below.

**- The table is large and you need to split the data in several partitions**

**- The table gets the first partition and you add new partition for new data**

Lets use this setup for the *not partitioned* table

```
create table jdbn.non_part 
 (id int not null, name varchar(100));

insert into jdbn.non_part (id,name)
SELECT  id, 'xxxxx'|| id::varchar(20) name
from generate_series(1,1000) id;
```

The table contains `id` from 1 to 1000 and for the first case you need to split them in two partition for 500 rows each.

**Create the partitioned table**

with identical structure and constraints as the original table

```
create table jdbn.part  
(like jdbn.non_part INCLUDING DEFAULTS INCLUDING CONSTRAINTS)
PARTITION BY RANGE (id);
```

**Add partitions**

to cover current data

```
create table jdbn.part_500 partition of jdbn.part
for values from (1) to (501); /* 1 <= id < 501 */

create table jdbn.part_1000 partition of jdbn.part
for values from (501) to (1001);
```

for future data (as required)

```
create table jdbn.part_1500 partition of jdbn.part
for values from (1001) to (1501);
```

**Use insert to copy data**

Note that this approach *copy* the data that means you need twice the space and a possible cleanup of the old data.

```
insert into jdbn.part (id,name)
select id, name from jdbn.non_part;
```

**Check partition pruning**

Note that only the partition `part_500` is accessed

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM jdbn.part WHERE id <= 500;

QUERY PLAN                                                      |
----------------------------------------------------------------+
Seq Scan on part_500 part  (cost=0.00..14.00 rows=107 width=222)|
  Filter: (id <= 500)                                           |
```

**Second Option - MOVE Data to one Partition**

If you can live with the one (big) initial partition, you may use the second approach

**Create the partitioned table**

same as above

**Attach the table as a partition**

```
ALTER TABLE jdbn.part ATTACH PARTITION jdbn.non_part
   for values from (1) to (1001);
```

Now the original table gets the first partition of your partitioned table. I.e. no data duplication is performed.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM jdbn.part WHERE id <= 500;
QUERY PLAN                                                     |
---------------------------------------------------------------+
Seq Scan on non_part part  (cost=0.00..18.50 rows=500 width=12)|
  Filter: (id <= 500)                                          |
```

Similar answer with some hints to automation of partition creation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53600145/4808122)

Comment: so my case is that it has many fields and I don't want to include the whole fields when copying data from one table to another.
@Marmite Bomber

Comment: And the issue that the fields are not sorted in the first one as in the second one

Answer (score 0):

After trying a few things, the solution was:

```
INSERT INTO new_table(fields ordered as the result of the select statement) SELECT * FROM old_table
```

I don't know if there was an easier way to get the fields ordered, but I tried inserting a row in DBEver from these options:

[image]

Then got names like these steps:

[image]